# Using VBS cannot click button. No ID

Tags: html, vbscript, click

I've tried some of the other suggestions on the site related to this topic, but I can't get this to work after spending many hours on it. Here is the code I have so far, followed by the snippet of code on the "Clear" button on the next form (after Search is clicked. Clicking search works and takes me to another form.)

```
Dim URL 
Dim IE 
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
IE.Top = 0
IE.Left = 0
URL = "https://ebsprod.utg.uvn.net:4443/OA_HTML/OA.jsp?page=/oracle/apps/icx/por/reqmgmt/webui/ReqSummaryPG&_ti=1826123697&oapc=7&OAMC=77445_134_0&menu=Y&oaMenuLevel=1&oas=liPV_eLrgEnGE1mwKwcf6A.." 
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate URL

 Do While IE.Busy
    WScript.Sleep 100
 Loop

IE.Document.getElementById("Search").Click
```

Snippet of where I'm stuck. Can't figure out how to click this button:

```
<button title="Clear" class="x7p" onclick="return _chain('clearclearButton(); return false;','submitForm(\'DefaultFormName\',0,{\'_FORM_SUBMIT_BUTTON\':\'clearButtonfOAmnJbM\'});return false',this,event,true)" type="submit">Clear</button>
```

Comment: See [getElementsByClassName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff975198(v=vs.80))

Comment: IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("x7p").Click                                   I tried already :-( It doesn't work. I get an error that the obj doesn't support the getElementsByClassName.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the code in "onclick" in a function like this:

```
 <button  title="Clear" class="x7p" onclick="myButtonClick()" type="submit">Clear</button>
```

VBS Code:

```
function myButtonClick()
        (the code you want to execute)
end function
```